# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package in pyspark/not able to find the kmodes module(pyspark)

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package in pyspark. Above error is coming when i am trying to use kmode in pyspark .So i parrelelize the kmode package by using 
sc.addFile("home/pyspark-distributedkmodesmaster/pyspark_kmodes/pyspark_kmodes.py") .If i am not using the sc context add file  code  it is throwing error -"not able to find the kmodes module".
I am using below code/link or kmodes pyspark package -
"https://github.com/ThinkBigAnalytics/pyspark-distributed-kmodes/blob/master/pyspark_kmodes"

Answer (score 1):

It's a package and you're only deploying one of the py files contained in it. Since there is a relative import in `pyspark_kmodes.py`:

```py
from .Kmodes import KModes
```

The `.` in  `.Kmodes` means it should look for file `KModes.py` in the same folder (within the package folder)

Comment: hey,thanks,I  merged all files in one py and then bring it spark context.It is working now